# Indesign - Paste Inline Image Resized to Frame Width

Tags: adobe-indesign, images

I'm inserting large inline images into my text flow, which it then breaks the flow and disappears. Is there a way to have it automatically resize to fit the text frame's boundaries?

Comment: do you really need in-line images? perhaps you should be using text wrap (aka runaround) or chaining text boxes

Comment: `Object > Fitting > Fit Content Proportionately`

Answer (score 0):

Make and adjust your graphic frame, then copy your image and 'Paste in to' instead of regular paste. Is this what you needed?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for InDesign to contextually scale inline images. However, if the images are single color vector images, you can import them as glyphs into a custom font using something like IndyFont. It turns InDesign into a font editor, allowing you to paste in vectors, and save it as a font (even a single-character font). InDesign treats the font glyphs like any other letters, accepting color swatches and scaling with the rest of the text.

Comment: BTW, there is a free version of IndyFont. Look it up.